# How to optimize React/Redux chat perfomance?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a chat based on React and Redux.

Chat container receives messageIds and using messageIds.map() I render component for each message. This component is connected to Redux, so it receives messageId and updates only if messageId was changed.

But in profiler I see a lot of (React Tree Reconciliation: Completed Root) events on new message received, which take about 6ms. How to prevent this reconcilitation or how to optimize it?

For example I have 30 messages in chat, and on each new message reconciliation takes about 6ms * 30 messages = 180 ms, even if message component was not rerendered. Below I provided screenshots of profiler.

[Message received action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPEii.png)

[Zoomed reconciliation event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM2Zc.png)

Comment: Wrap your message component in React.memo or if message component is a class then inherit from React.PureComponent. I need to see message component and it's container to give more helpful advice.

Comment: @HMR from React side components are optimized, I am using shouldComponentUpdate and PureComponent as well, but by profiler, it looks like Redux trying to update message component. In profiler I see:
1. Connect(MessageItemContainer) [update]
1.2. Connect(MessageItemContainer).shouldComponentUpdate
1.3. Connect(MessageItemContainer).componentWillUpdate
1.4. Connect(MessageItemContainer).getChildContext
1.5. MessageItemContainer.shouldComponentUpdate

Comment: If you're not extending from React.PureComponent than and implement shouldComponentUpdate than I'd like to see the shouldComponentUpdate and where the props come from as well as what you pass as props from the parent of the message item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example with 3 common mistakes using react-redux connect and needless re renders:

1. mapStateToProps always returns a new object (`state=>({val:{new:reference}})` you can prevent this by memoizing the result: `()=>{const memoizedResult=createSelector(...);return state=>memoizedResult(state)`
2. Passing a new object as prop every time (called bad prop)
3. Passing a new function as callback every time (called bad callback prop)

```js
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore } = Redux;

const store = createStore(() =>
  //reducer always returns a new object
  ({
    val: 1,
  })
);
function App({ a }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={a}>re render</button>
      <BadContainer message="bad container" />
      <GoodContainer
        message="bad prop"
        badProp={{ a: 22 }}
      />
      <GoodContainer
        message="bad callback prop"
        badCallback={() => 88}
      />
      <GoodContainer message="good container" />
    </div>
  );
}
function Message(props) {
  const rendered = React.useRef(0);
  rendered.current++;
  return (
    <div>
      {props.message} rendered: {rendered.current} times
    </div>
  );
}
const AppContainer = connect(() => ({ a: {} }), {
  a: () => ({ type: 'a' }),
})(App);
const BadContainer = connect(state =>
  //bad map state, always returns new object for props
  ({
    object: { newObject: state.val },
  })
)(Message);
const GoodContainer = connect(() => {
  //prepare memoized function that will only re create props
  //  if parameters to it changed (usually done with reselect)
  const memProps = ((lastVal, lastResult) => val => {
    if (lastVal !== val) {
      lastResult = {
        object: { newObject: val },
      };
      lastVal = val;
    }
    return lastResult;
  })();
  //return optimized map state to props using memoization
  return state => memProps(state.val);
}, {})(Message);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.4/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.1.1/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```